# When i run subquery (trigger) in stored procedure, then i get error. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

When I tried to run my procedure (smažPoložky_SP) and delete some rows I get

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression

because my trigger. (trigger instead of delete)

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER zkontrolujMnožství ON Zboží
 INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
 DECLARE @p_mnozstvi INTEGER = (SELECT množstvíSklad FROM deleted) -- Getting number of goods
BEGIN 
 IF @p_mnozstvi < 0 -- Try to know if is empty 
     EXECUTE vyvolej_chybu_sp 15 -- Raise error
 ELSE 
     DELETE FROM Zboží WHERE (SELECT zbožíID FROM deleted) = zbožíID 
END;
```

```sql
alter PROCEDURE testSmazani (@id_jednotky INTEGER) AS 
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION  /* SELECT for get information if id exists */
            IF EXISTS(SELECT měrnáJednotkaID FROM MěrnéJednotky WHERE měrnáJednotkaID = @id_jednotky)
                BEGIN 
                    /* This delete is error because my = in trigger */
                    DELETE FROM Zboží WHERE měrnáJednotka = @id_jednotky  
                    DELETE FROM MěrnéJednotky WHERE měrnáJednotkaID = @id_jednotky
                    COMMIT;
                end
                else
                rollback
END;
```

Comment: Did you mean `DECLARE @p_mnozstvi INTEGER = (SELECT Count( množstvíSklad ) FROM deleted)`?

Comment: Your trigger *assumes* a `DELETE`contains 1 row (`DECLARE @p_mnozstvi INTEGER = (SELECT množstvíSklad FROM deleted)`), it shouldn't. A `DELETE` can contain 1 **or more** rows and a trigger is fired once for a single DML operation (not once per row). As such, if your `DELETE` has more than 1 row, the object `deleted` will contain multiple rows too and the highlighted SQL will fail. The line `DELETE FROM Zboží WHERE (SELECT zbožíID FROM deleted) = zbožíID` also makes the same assumption.

Answer (score 2):

In your trigger, this line:

```
DELETE FROM Zboží WHERE (SELECT zbožíID FROM deleted) = zbožíID
```

Will error if `deleted` contains more than one row.

Simply write it this way instead:

```
DELETE FROM Zboží WHERE zbožíID IN (SELECT zbožíID FROM deleted)
```

Also, the way you are declaring and populating `@p_mnozstvi` will also error if `deleted` contains more than one row.

It wouldn't error if you did it this way, but you may get unexpected results:

```
DECLARE @p_mnozstvi INTEGER;
SELECT @p_mnozstvi = množstvíSklad FROM deleted;
```

It would probably be better to re-think how you want to handle this part of the logic when `deleted` contains multiple rows.   Maybe use `EXISTS()` to check if any row contains a value of zero (or not zero, depending on how you want to handle it).

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is not taking into account that `deleted` could have more than one row.  It is not clear what you want to do exactly, but it looks like you need a loop:

```
CREATE TRIGGER zkontrolujMnožství ON Zboží INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS BEGIN 
    DECLARE @p_mnozstvi INTEGER;
    DECLARE d_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT množstvíSklad FROM deleted;

    OPEN d_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM d_cursor INTO @p_mnozstvi;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        IF @p_mnozstvi < 0 -- Try to know if is empty 
            EXECUTE vyvolej_chybu_sp 15; -- Raise error
        ELSE 
            DELETE FROM Zboží WHERE zbožíID IN (SELECT zbožíID FROM deleted);
    END;
    CLOSE db_cursor; 
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
END;
```

As much as I dislike cursors, if you want to call a stored procedure for each value, that is probably the best approach.

EDIT:

If you want to raise an error if *any* of the values are negative, then you don't need a cursor:

```
CREATE TRIGGER zkontrolujMnožství ON Zboží INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS BEGIN     
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted WHERE množstvíSklad < 0)
        EXECUTE vyvolej_chybu_sp 15; -- Raise error
    ELSE 
        DELETE FROM Zboží
            WHERE zbožíID IN (SELECT zbožíID FROM deleted);
END;
```